# MySQL Check drop children over certain age

Tags: mysql

I’m creating a database for a Union, in this relation Members (MID) can have multiple children included in their membership, however this only counts if the children is under the age of 24.

Whenever a person gets above the age of 24, I would want that person to be removed from the table. The `Children` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Children
(
   MID int NOT NULL,  -- Parent
   DOB DATE NOT NULL,
   Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY(MID) REFERENCES Member(MID),
   CONSTRAINT check_age CHECK (TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, DOB, CURDATE()) < 24)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

What is wrong with the constraint? If I execute this query it doesn’t get removed as expected:

```
INSERT INTO Children(MID,DOB,Name) VALUES (4,"1988-12-25","Sussie");
```

Comment: Apart from the logic considerations, MySQL does not actually implement `check` constraints.  You need to use a trigger for the logic.  The documentation says "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. " (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Comment: I would ask though, whether you really want to delete the dependents >= age 24. Could you keep them in place in the table, and not include them when querying or do you really wish to remove them?

Comment: I thought about it, and it might be best to just ignore them when doing queries.